# появление select в зависимости от выбора в предыдущем selet

Tags: php, html, html5, html-select

У меня есть вот такой код, как сделать так чтобы при выборе какого-то значения из первого select например значения Максим, появлялся select из $column_two_v2, а при других значениях первого select из $column_two?

```
    <?php
$column_one = [
    "1" => "Максим",
    "2" => "Василий",
    "3" => "Евгений",
    "4" => "Владимир",
];
$column_two = [
    "1" => "Евтушенко",
    "2" => "Петров",
    "3" => "Долгополов",
    "4" => "Неуструев",
];
$column_two_v2 = [
    "1" => "Аношкин",
    "2" => "Афанасьеф",
    "3" => "Петров",
    "4" => "Чехов",
];

 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style1.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/SidePanel.css" type="text/css">
  <script defer src="../JavaScript/step.js "> </script>
</head>


<body>
<?php require "../blocks/SidePanel.php" ?>

  <div class="fullscr">
    <?php
    $step = 0;
    echo "<form method=\"POST\">";
    echo "<table class=\"style1\">";
    if ($step == 0) {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>1 столбик</td>";
        echo "<td>2 столбик</td>";
        echo "<td>3 столбик</td>";
        echo "<td>4 столбик</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
      if ($step == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><select name=\"one\" id =\"one\" onChange=\"HiddenOne();\" class=\"replSelect\">";
          //echo "<option hidden></option>";
          foreach ($column_one as $key => $value) {

            echo "<option>$value</option>";
          }
        echo "</select></td>";
        $step ++;
      }
        if ($step == 1) {
          echo "<td><select hidden name=\"two\" id =\"two\" onChange=\"HiddenTwo();\">";
          if ((ISSET($_POST['one']))=='Максим') {
            foreach ($column_two_v2 as $key => $value) {
              echo "<option>$value</option>";
            }
          }
```